# Flink-SQL: Extract values from nested objects

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

i'm using Flink SQL and the following scheme shows my source data (belonging to some Twitter data):

```
CREATE TABLE `twitter_raw` (
    `entities` ROW(
        `hashtags` ROW(
            `text` STRING,
            `indices` INT ARRAY
        ) ARRAY,
        `urls` ROW(
            `indices` INT ARRAY,
            `url` STRING,
            `display_url` STRING,
            `expanded_url` STRING
        ) ARRAY,
        `user_mentions` ROW(
            `screen_name` STRING,
            `name` STRING,
            `id` BIGINT
        ) ARRAY
    )
)
WITH (...);
```

I want to get only the hashtags in a collection. Therefore i have to map the collection of constructed objects (ROW) to an array of STRING.

Like this scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE `twitter_raw` (
    `entities` ROW(
        `hashtags` STRING ARRAY,
        `urls` STRING ARRAY,
        `user_mentions` STRING ARRAY
    )
)
WITH (...);
```

How can i achieve this with Flink-SQL? Maybe built-in functions (JSON-functions?) or own UDF or do i have to write a DataStream Job?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL command `UNNEST` helps in this case. It is like `EXPLODE` in Spark.

You can solve it by creating a new row  for each hashtag in the `hashtags` array:

```sql
SELECT hashtag, index
FROM twitter_raw 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hashtags) AS t (hashtag, index)
```

Comment: FYI, Unnest is useful for Map data type as well

Answer (score 1):

You can either define a [computed row](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/create/#columns), or a VIEW, and then extracting the hashtags field using the dot notation. e.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW hashtags_raw (hashtags) AS 
  SELECT entities.hashtags AS hashtags FROM twitter_raw
```

Comment: This view does not fix the problem of accessing the individual fields of the array.